# Программирование краевой задачи

Tags: c++, математика, дискретная-математика

Как запрограммировать задачку на С++?

Условие: решить краевую задачу

> y"=-a^2(y')^2 - 1; y(0)=y(1)=0; a=0,7

Результат: представить графически.

Никогда не сталкивался с такого рода.

Comment: Обычному человеку зачем краевая задача? Что она вам даст? это наверняка лабораторка, к ней есть инструкция. Если сделать не тем методом который от вас ожидают - незачтут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Гы, в Интернете такого не найдешь - это точно. Это эллиптическое уравнение 2-го порядка. Решается методом разностных схем. Очень напоминает уравнение диффузионной волны (квадрат первой производной) - стационарное и упрощенный вид  часть уравнения Навье-Стокса.

Почитайте труды академика Самарского про теорию разностных схем.

Скорее всего здесь надо будет применить 3-х точечная разностная схема (приводит к 3-х диагональной матрице). Задача сведется к обращению этой матрицы.

В общем здесь начать и закончить.